# How does awk's ^ (caret) exclusion work?

Tags: regex, linux, awk

I got shown the below (running on fedora 24):

Input example:

```
/sys/devices/system/memory/memory101/state:offline
/sys/devices/system/memory/memory104/state:offline
/sys/devices/system/memory/memory107/state:offline
```

AWK command executed on the input:

```
grep offline data/onlineMemory | awk -F '[^0-9]+' {'print $2'}
```

which gives output like:

```
101
104
107
```

But when I print awk's `$1`, I see nothing. Where has the other part of the lines gone?

Why is `$2` set to the digits? I thought `^` in awk would negate the characters.

Comment: Although you already accepted an answer (mine, in fact), it would be good to [edit] to clarify what is your exact expected output, because it may well happen that you also want to print some specific part of the string together with the numbers.

Comment: The character is called *caret.* A carat is a unit of measurement for diamond weight and purity of gold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is weird, but normal: since you are setting the field separator to `[^0-9]+`, `awk` understands this as: everything is a field separator apart from the digits.

```
#field1                                              field3
#<|                                                  |>
#  /sys/devices/system/memory/memory101/state:offline
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#              FS                   ^^^       FS
#                                   field2
```

This way, almost everything in your string becomes a field separator:

```
$ awk -F '[^0-9]+' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "line=%d. field num %d is --> %s\n", NR, i, $i}' file
line=1. field num 1 is --> 
line=1. field num 2 is --> 101
line=1. field num 3 is --> 
line=2. field num 1 is --> 
line=2. field num 2 is --> 104
line=2. field num 3 is --> 
line=3. field num 1 is --> 
line=3. field num 2 is --> 107
line=3. field num 3 is -->
```

Why is this happening? Because the way `awk` sets the fields:
It sets the 1st one to everything up to the FS, then the 2nd from the 1st to the 2nd FS and so on; finally, the last field (`$NF`) consists in everything from the last FS up to the end of the record:

```
$ awk -F ';' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "line=%d. field num %d is --> %s\n", NR, i, $i}' <<< ";hello;"
line=1. field num 1 is --> 
line=1. field num 2 is --> hello
line=1. field num 3 is -->
```

So in this case you are making the `FS` be something rather complex, which can be summarized with this example where the FS is anything but `3`:

```
$ awk -F '[^3]+' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "line=%d. field num %d is --> %s\n", NR, i, $i}' <<< "abcde3fghi"
line=1. field num 1 is --> 
line=1. field num 2 is --> 3
line=1. field num 3 is -->
```

So what `awk` is doing in this case is to split the string `abcde3fghi` using the FS `anything but 3`, making everything before the first FS to be the first field (hence empty) and everything after the last occurrence of FS the last field (hence also empty). This leaves us just a single not-empty field, the 2nd one.

Comment: Amazing answer, helps me understand what is going on. All I want is the number from each line, is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: @Dan yes, just print [`NR`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset) (number of record; that is, number of line in this case). So for example you can say `{print $2, NR}` to print the match and then the line number.

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
/sys/devices/system/memory/memory101/state:offline
```

Field separator is `/sys/devices/system/memory/memory` because there are no digits in it.

On the left of the separator there's nothing, and on the right, your number, since it does not fit in the separator regex